# Proguard with scala and android-plugin: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 160

Tags: java, android, scala, proguard, sbt-android-plugin

Here is my complete log: [log](http://paste.awesom.eu/bPl)

I use scala, sbt and android-plugin. I have a lot of imports so it might be the reason why I get that. Someone seemed to have the same problem and resolved it by "battling with proguard".
[github issue](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/issues/121)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this problem has been fixed in more recent versions of ProGuard. You can simply replace the directory `tools/proguard` in the Android SDK (or even just `tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar`). If that doesn't help, please file a bug report on the [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) site.

Comment: If you catch the exception in the utility clas proguard.classfile.util.DescriptorClassEnumeration, you can also just mail me the descriptor string on which ProGuard fails. (I am the developer of ProGuard)

Comment: I've deleted some library which I dont really use and it works now. If i  encouter again the problem I will mail you.

Comment: I'd still prefer to fix the problem. Could you mail me that library or point me to it?

Comment: the Library I used is finagle-core and finagle-thrift version 5.3.1. Removing them from libraryDependencies fix my problem. Someone seem to have find a solution to make it works anyway. It's to use  compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala